# Powershell: New-SMBshare cmdlet not working on remote server

Tags: powershell, share, smb

I am trying to make an all-in-one script which will create a share folder on a server, permission it (NTFS), share it, set share permissions, then set the DFS folder and target. All of this works fine so far (at least in individual parts), except for the Share part.

My code looks OK.

To test, If I create/permission the share locally, there is no problem. Example:

New-SmbShare –Name test1 –Path C:\test -FullAccess Administrators

This works fine.

BUT, if I try the same on the server, I get this error: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." Example:

New-SmbShare -name test1 -path \ \server\e$\data -FullAccess Administrators

I am not sure what the error means (Google was not either), but I am wondering if I am entering the server address syntax incorrectly...or is remote share creation even possible with Powershell? Every example I have seen on the web shows a local creation.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using two backslashes before the server name? Such as `\\Server01\E$\Test`?

Comment: Yes, I am, but for some reason only one of them shows up in these forums. I'll space them out.

Comment: What if you used `New-SmbMapping` to map `\\server\e$` to a drive like `K:` and then use `New-SmbShare` to share the `K:\Data` dir?  It seems like the command is choking on the UNC path.

Answer (score 1):

The New-SmbShare cmdlet will use a cimsession for remote management (via winrm).

Based off your question here is an example and the help reference below.

```
$c = new-CimSession -ComputerName Server
New-SmbShare -Name test1 -Path E:\data -CimSession $c



PS C:\> get-help New-SmbShare -Parameter cimsession

-CimSession <CimSession[]>
    Runs the cmdlet in a remote session or on a remote computer. Enter a computer name or a session object, such as
    the output of a New-CimSession or Get-CimSession cmdlet. The default is the current session on the local computer.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```